# Добавить поле ввода в окне интерфейса. PySimpleGui

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pillow, pysimplegui

Хочу сделать окно ввода чтобы по нажатию кнопки "загрузить письма" происходила обработка и в изображение добавлялось слово, в зависимости от введенного, не получилось разобраться, сделал пока по-колхозному через консоль так:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
from tqdm import tqdm


sg.theme("SystemDefaultForReal")

layout = [
 [sg.Submit("Загрузить письма", size=(27, 2), font=20)],
#[sg.Text('Месяц', size =(15, 1)), sg.InputText()],
]

window = sg.Window('Letter', icon='1.ico').Layout(layout)

while True:                             # The Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    # print(event, values) #debug
    if event == 'Загрузить письма':
        xlsx = pd.read_excel("obr.xlsx")
        c = []
        month = input("Введите месяц с заглавной буквы\n")
        print("1 этап из 1:")
        for ind in tqdm(range(len(xlsx))):
            if xlsx.iloc[ind]['A60'] == "письмо" or xlsx.iloc[ind]['A60'] == "звонок":
                image = Image.open("shabl.jpg")
                font1 = ImageFont.truetype("times.ttf", 50)
                drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
                if month == "Январь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "январе", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Февраль":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "феврале", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Март":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "марте", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Апрель":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "апреле", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Май":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "мае", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Июнь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "июне", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Июль":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "июле", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Август":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "августе", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Сентябрь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "сентябре", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Октябрь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "октябре", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Ноябрь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "ноябре", font=font1, fill='black')
                if month == "Декабрь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "декабре", font=font1, fill='black')
                image.save(f"C:/pict/other{ind}.jpg")
    if event in (None, 'Exit', 'Закрыть'):
        break
```

Comment: На сами файлы могу сделать ссылку на архив, чтобы можно было запустить код

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так, почему то обычный else не отрабатывает, пришлось воспользоваться elif:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd
sg.theme("SystemDefaultForReal")

xlsx = pd.read_excel("obr.xlsx")

layout = [
    [sg.Button("Загрузить письма", size=(27, 2), font=20)],
    [sg.Text('Введите месяц:', size=(15, 1)), sg.InputText(key='-MONTH-', do_not_clear=False)],
    [sg.ProgressBar(len(xlsx), orientation='h', size=(20, 20), key='progressbar')]]

window = sg.Window('Letter', icon='1.ico').Layout(layout)
while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == 'Загрузить письма':
        step = 1
        for ind in range(len(xlsx)):
            window['progressbar'].update(step)
            step += 1
            if xlsx.iloc[ind]['A60'] == "письмо" or xlsx.iloc[ind]['A60'] == "звонок":
                image = Image.open("shabl.jpg")
                font1 = ImageFont.truetype("times.ttf", 50)
                drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Январь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "январе", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Февраль":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "феврале", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Март":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "марте", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Апрель":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "апреле", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Май":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "мае", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Июнь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "июне", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Июль":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "июле", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Август":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "августе", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Сентябрь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "сентябре", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Октябрь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "октябре", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Ноябрь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "ноябре", font=font1, fill='black')
                if values['-MONTH-'] == "Декабрь":
                    drawer.text((1030, 981), "декабре", font=font1, fill='black')
                elif (values['-MONTH-'] != "Декабрь"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Январь"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Февраль"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Март"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Апрель"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Май"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Июнь"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Июль"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Август"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Сентябрь"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Октябрь"
                        and values['-MONTH-'] != "Ноябрь"):
                    sg.Popup('Введите месяц с заглавной буквы!')
                    break
                image.save(f"C:/pict/other{ind}.jpg")
    if event in (None, 'Exit', 'Закрыть'):
        break
window.close()
```